# Create self-signed SSL certificate for windows XP

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-xp

How can I create an SSL certificate pair for a windows XP machine.  Is it possible to do without enabling IIS?

Some background:

1. Splunk server on hardened Windows XP machine - yes I know, not the most ideal
2. Trying to contact our IPS from this machine, but the IPS requires an authorized public key from the machine contacting it.  This is why we're trying to make one.
3. We do not want to enable IIS on the XP machine if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating self-signed certificates has nothing to do with enabling IIS, but you can use a self-signed certificate to configure IIS to enable https if needed.

You can find many links on how to generate self-signed certificates like [this one](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) and [this one](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html). You need to have openssl toolkit in your machine.